# Most browsers don't work properly on my Ubuntu 21.10

Tags: firefox, google-chrome

I have chrome,edge and Firefox that won't start or take long to start, and if they do start they only work in private mode.

the only browser connecting too the internet atm is the gnome Epiphany browser.

most of my software work properly and launches fast , the browsers don't work at all.

I don't use extensions. i am confused since it is both Firefox and chrome based browsers.

Comment: Did you upgrade to 21.10 or is it a fresh install?  If it's an upgrade, try creating a new user account and see if you have the same problems with that?

Comment: same problem with firefox and brave. I uninstalled brave and things are working better now. And I just upg

Comment: Are these snap apps? Do `snap list` to find out. Report back.

Comment: Only firefox, it is a fresh install. i did a zfs snapshot restore from grub and now edge is started working again.

Comment: I meet this problem too.
Ubuntu don't want render browser window if I run it. Then I remove firefox from terminal use command "snap remove firefox"
Then I install from official site manual using "sudo apt-get update" & "sudo apt install Firefox"
And it's run wery well. Problem was at snap version of Firefox!!!